# put marquee if text is more than one line

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to use a `<marquee>` for a `<span>` if the `div` content is more than one line.

If content is less than one line, don't use a marquee, but if greater than one line, I want the content to display with a marquee.

Any help is appreciated, I need some suggestions.

This is okay:

```
<div id="statusdiv">
    <span id="status">some status here</span>
</div>
```

---

but if this is case

```
<div id="statusdiv">
    <span id="status">loooooooooooooooooooong status here</span>
</div>
```

then, code should change to

```
<div id="statusdiv">
    <marquee id="status">loooooooooooooooooooong status here</marquee>
</div>
```

Comment: i really doubt if this is possible with css, css is not meant for such things

Comment: <marquee> is obsolete. You should really look into alternatives. There are a lot of JQuery plugins that handle this kind of behavior.

Comment: With Jquery I think you can do one thing check height of element with single line and then check if element.height()>oneline height please do your stuff

Comment: I have a demo if you want I can share it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I have changed `id` to `class` to show multiple examples

```js
$('.statusdiv').each(function() {
  var th = $(this);
  var ih = $(this).outerHeight(); // outer height
  var oh = $(this).find('.status').outerHeight(); // inner height
  var txt = $(this).find('.status').html(); // so that the inline styles remains the same

  // if outer height is less that inner hieight

  if (oh > ih) {
    th.html('');
    th.html('<marquee class="status">' + txt + '</marquee>')
  }
});
```

```css
.statusdiv {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.statusdiv > .status {
  line-height: 30px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="statusdiv">
  <span class="status"><strong>Vestibulum</strong> status here In turpis. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Fusce fermentum <strong>Vestibulum</strong> nec arcu. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent <strong>Vestibulum</strong>.</span>
</div>

<div class="statusdiv">
  <span class="status">some status here In turpis. <strong>Vestibulum</strong> purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Fusce fermentum odio nec arcu. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient monte.</span>
</div>

<div class="statusdiv">
  <span class="status">some status here In turpis. scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. </span>
</div>

<div class="statusdiv">
  <span class="status">some status here In turpis. scelerisque</span>
</div>
```

Comment: learned a new thing that can do with `class` and this is exactly what i need. but, if there is a list of hundreds, can you spot out any _performance issue_ in **phonegap**?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the html tag "span" to marquee based on div height. check below it will works for you. 20 is the line height I hardcoded you can change that one based on your requirement.

```js
var clientHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').clientHeight;

alert(clientHeight);
if(clientHeight > 20){
 
// changing the html tag span to marquee if line height more than 20.
 
 $('span').contents().unwrap().wrap('<marquee/>');
  
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <span class="text">dasdfasasdas asdfasdfa asdfasdfa asdf asdfa fasd asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfads asdfa dsd asdf asd fasdf asdf asdf asd fasd fasdf as dfasdf asd asd asdf asdf</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please remove alert(clientHeight);  from the code. for demo i have added.